# phpstorm 7 smarty-like statements in html-embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, html, smarty, phpstorm

I often embed JavaScript-code in HTML templates via tag script, and use Smarty-like statements in the code like this:

```
<script>
{if $debug}
    var debug = true;
{else}
    var debug = false;
{/if}
</script>
```

but PhpStorm shows a lot of warnings - such as "expected something else," or, if I comment out the statement, "Duplicate" and so on, and it's annoying. Is there a way to make PhpStorm understand these statements as I expect (like if-statement)?

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicate declaration` error is because you are declaring the same variable twice. Even if that never happens (because of the `if, else`), PHPStorm will still detect it as "possibly happening".

It's totally okay to ignore these warnings if your own logic is correct. But if you really want to get rid of it, you can do it as following:

```
<script>
    var debug = false;
    {if $debug}
        debug = true;
    {/if}
</script>
```

I don't get the `expected something else` warning, so it must be caused by something else in your code.